# How do I ensure that a foreign key exists as a primary key in another table when data is inserted?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

This is an example of some tables that I'm using.

```
create TABLE People(
peopleID int not null,
name varchar(40) not null,
primary key (peopleID)
);


create table car(
carID int not null,
peopleID int not null,
primary key (carID),
foreign key (peopleID) references People(peopleID)
);
```

How do I ensure that when I insert into 'car', the 'peopleID' foreign key exists as a primary key in the table 'People'.

For example, I would want the following statement to throw an error:

```
INSERT INTO car VALUES (123, 343);
```

... because 343 doesn't exist in 'PeopleID', as it is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You have described what the `foreign key` constraint *does*:

> For storage engines supporting foreign keys, MySQL rejects any INSERT
>   or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a
>   child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the
>   parent table.

The constraint is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).